# Create new Visual C++ project based on existing project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have a library project in a VC++ 2008 solution. I'd like to split it into two projects, both having the same project settings. I can't see an easy way to do this, is it possible?

Comment: Project file is a text file. Make a copy of the file and write a python script which will replace certain parts of it with something else.

Comment: I'd have to learn Python in that case. But it seems something along those lines is needed, which is irritating.

Comment: Yes, copy the file, edit them in good-old notepad using search and replace.  Add the two project files to a new solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i generally copy paste the .vcproj file then replace the project name in the new one :)

maybe it is not the best way but it always works :)